# parse error on input `let' with multiple let blocks

Tags: haskell, syntax

I am trying to define a function with a number of let statements, but I keep getting an error `parse error on input 'let'`. I'm still new to Haskell so I can't actually see what is causing this problem.

Here is my function:

```
myFunc :: ([String], Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) -> ([String], Int)
nextGuess (prev_string, prev_int) (a1, a2, a3) = (new_string, new_int)
    let new_int_1 = if a3 - a1 < 0
        then prev_int
        else (filter (myPred1 a3 prev_string) prev_int)
    let new_int_2 = if a2 - a1 < 0
        then new_int_1
        else (filter (myPred2 a2 prev_string) new_int_1)
    new_int = filter (myPred3 a1 prev_string) new_int_2
```

I won't explain what the function is supposed to do because that is irrelevant to the question, my main issue is that there is a parse error on the first `let` statement and I don't know why.

Comment: Others have already answered about the difference between `let`…`in` and `where` here. But as for indentation, a good rule of thumb is that you won’t get into trouble (and won’t need to do fiddly alignment of things) if you just newline+indent after layout keywords such as `do`, `let`, `where`, `case`…`of`, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're defining functions by `let` after using the functions, but `let` is for opposite purpose.

You might want to read [Let vs. Where](https://wiki.haskell.org/Let_vs._Where) article, because you can use `where` here:

```
nextGuess (prev_string, prev_int) (a1, a2, a3) = (new_string, new_int)
    where
      new_int_1 = if a3 - a1 < 0
        then prev_int
        else (filter (myPred1 a3 prev_string) prev_int)
      new_int_2 = if a2 - a1 < 0
        then new_int_1
        else (filter (myPred2 a2 prev_string) new_int_1)
      new_int = filter (myPred3 a1 prev_string) new_int_2
```

Or `let in`:

```
nextGuess (prev_string, prev_int) (a1, a2, a3) =
    let new_int_1 = if a3 - a1 < 0
          then prev_int
          else (filter (myPred1 a3 prev_string) prev_int)
        new_int_2 = if a2 - a1 < 0
          then new_int_1
          else (filter (myPred2 a2 prev_string) new_int_1)
        new_int = filter (myPred3 a1 prev_string) new_int_2
      in
          (new_string, new_int)
```

Or `do notation`:

```
nextGuess (prev_string, prev_int) (a1, a2, a3) = do
    let new_int_1 = if a3 - a1 < 0
          then prev_int
          else (filter (myPred1 a3 prev_string) prev_int)
    let new_int_2 = if a2 - a1 < 0
          then new_int_1
          else (filter (myPred2 a2 prev_string) new_int_1)
    let new_int = filter (myPred3 a1 prev_string) new_int_2
    (new_string, new_int)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`let`-expressions](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-440003.12) should be in the form

```
let pattern_1 = expression_1
    pattern_2 = expression_2
    ...
in final_expression
```

so in your case, something like this:

```
myFunc :: ([String], Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) -> ([String], Int)
nextGuess (prev_string, prev_int) (a1, a2, a3) =
    let new_int_1 = if a3 - a1 < 0
            then prev_int
            else (filter (myPred1 a3 prev_string) prev_int)
        new_int_2 = if a2 - a1 < 0
            then new_int_1
            else (filter (myPred2 a2 prev_string) new_int_1)
        new_int = filter (myPred3 a1 prev_string) new_int_2
    in (new_string, new_int)
```

(There is a use of `let` inside [`do`-expressions](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14) that doesn't require `in`, but that's special.)

Alternately, the additional declarations can be inside the optional [`where`](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-830004.4.3) of the binding.

```
myFunc :: ([String], Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) -> ([String], Int)
nextGuess (prev_string, prev_int) (a1, a2, a3) = (new_string, new_int) where
    new_int_1 = if a3 - a1 < 0
        then prev_int
        else (filter (myPred1 a3 prev_string) prev_int)
    new_int_2 = if a2 - a1 < 0
        then new_int_1
        else (filter (myPred2 a2 prev_string) new_int_1)
    new_int = filter (myPred3 a1 prev_string) new_int_2
```